# How to check if XGBoost uses the GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I'm writing a pytest file to check if my machine learning libraries use the GPU. For Tensorflow I can check this with `tf.config.list_physical_devices()`. For XGBoost I've so far checked it by looking at GPU utilization (`nvdidia-smi`) while running my software. But how can I check this in a simple test? Something similar to the test I have for Tensorflow would do.

```
import pytest
import tensorflow as tf
import xgboost

# Marking all tests to be GPU dependent
pytestmark = pytest.mark.gpu

def test_tf_finds_gpu():
    """Check if Tensorflow finds the GPU."""
    assert tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")

def test_xgb_finds_gpu():
    """Check if XGBoost finds the GPU."""
    ...
    # What can I write here?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that `tree_method="gpu_hist"` is deprecated and will stop / has stopped working since `xgboost==2.0.0`. Histogram type and device are currently split into two parameters: `tree_method` (an unfortunate overwriting of the existing parameter, but with a different set of permitted levels) and a new one called `device`:

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb

xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor( # tree_method="gpu_hist" # deprecated
    tree_method="hist",
    device="cuda"
)

X = np.random.rand(50, 2)
y = np.random.randint(2, size=50)

xgb_model.fit(X, y)

xgb_model
```

Output when GPU access works correctly (no warnings):

```
XGBRegressor(base_score=None, booster=None, callbacks=None,
             colsample_bylevel=None, colsample_bynode=None,
             colsample_bytree=None, device='cuda',
             early_stopping_rounds=None,
             enable_categorical=False, eval_metric=None, feature_types=None,
             gamma=None, grow_policy=None, importance_type=None,
             interaction_constraints=None, learning_rate=None, max_bin=None,
             max_cat_threshold=None, max_cat_to_onehot=None,
             max_delta_step=None, max_depth=None, max_leaves=None,
             min_child_weight=None, missing=nan, monotone_constraints=None,
             multi_strategy=None, n_estimators=None, n_jobs=None,
             num_parallel_tree=None, random_state=None, ...)
```

vs.

No GPU access - a warning that the `device` argument has not been used:

```
[11:43:35] WARNING: ../src/learner.cc:767: 
Parameters: { "device" } are not used.
```

Answer (score 5):

The testing method I went with was running with `tree_method="gpu_hist"`. Depending on circumstances I couldn't pin down, this either raises an error or prints a warning if no GPU can be found.

So if no GPU can be found, the following test will catch it in one of two ways:

- raise an `XGBoostError` on `xgb_model.fit(X, y)`
- print a warning on `xgb_model.fit(X, y)`. This will be captured by the `capsys` fixture provided by pytest and either `captured.out` or `captured.err` will not be empty. Hence, one of the asserts will raise an `AssertionError`.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_diabetes
import xgboost as xgb

def test_xgb_finds_gpu(capsys):
    """Check if XGBoost finds the GPU."""
    dataset = load_diabetes()
    X = dataset["data"]
    y = dataset["target"]
    xgb_model = xgb.XGBRegressor(
        # If there is no GPU, the tree_method kwarg will cause either
        # - an error in `xgb_model.fit(X, y)` (seen with pytest) or
        # - a warning printed to the console (seen in Spyder)
        # It's unclear which of the two happens under what circumstances.
        tree_method="gpu_hist"
    )
    xgb_model.fit(X, y)
    # Check that no warning was printed.
    captured = capsys.readouterr()
    assert captured.out == ""
    assert captured.err == ""
```

I think that this test can be sped up by using smaller arrays for `X` and `y` but implementing this takes too much of my time, given that the test only takes a few seconds without the GPU and less than a second with the GPU.

Comment: Would be helpful if you update your example as the sample dataset is not available any more: 
`load_boston` has been removed from scikit-learn since version 1.2.

The Boston housing prices dataset has an ethical problem ...

Comment: From the docs, it looks like `load_diabetes` can be used here instead without any changes. I don't have a suitable testing environment though, so I'll leave the answer as is. Anyone, feel free to edit if you find a test that works in scikit-learn 1.2 or later!

Comment: I'm using `from sklearn.datasets import load_wine` and `XGBClassifier` since `load_boston` has been removed from `scikit-learn` since version 1.2

Comment: @AlexNeaKameni feel free to edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I didn't see a warning when running this in the console with xgb 1.7.6 (no pytest). I would recommend the answer given below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77187203/4691830